# Tangent Space of $\operatorname{Aut}(T_e G)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie Group, how to prove that the tangent Space of $\operatorname{Aut}(T_e G)$ at identity is $\operatorname{End}(T_e G)$? Thanks.

Comment: Automorphisms and endomorphisms of $T_e G$ as what kind of object? Vector space? Lie algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $E$ is a Banach space. Let $B(E)$ be the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators on $E$, equipped with the induced operator norm. You can call it the algebra of endomorphisms if you prefer. Then denote $GL(E)$ the group of invertible elements in $B(E)$, that is the group of automorphisms.

Fix $T_0$ in $GL(E)$. Then for very $S\in B(E)$ such that $\|S\|<\frac{1}{\|T_0^{-1}\|}$, we have $T_0+S$ in $GL(E)$ with inverse given by
$$
(T_0+S)^{-1}=T_0^{-1}(I+ST_0^{-1})^{-1}=T_0^{-1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-ST_0^{-1})^n.
$$
The convergence of the Neumann series is due to the fact that $\|ST_0^{-1}\|\leq\|S\|\|T_0^{-1}\|<1$.

This proves that $GL(E)$ is open in $B(E)$, therefore it is a manifold modeled on $B(E)$.

In your case $E=T_eG$, $GL(E)=\operatorname{Aut}(T_eG)$ and $B(E)=\operatorname{End}(T_eG)$.

Actually, the same argument proves more generally that the set of invertible elements in a Banach algebra is open, hence a manifold modeled on this Banach algebra.

Comment: Why do you prove that $GL(E)$ is a manifold, when this should be already known just in order to formulate the question? Besides, here $E$ is just a finite-dimensional vector space, no series are needed. Just use that the determinant is a continuous map from $\mathrm{End}(E)$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If the manifold structure was that well known by the OP, he/she would not have asked the question which follows instantly from the definition of the manifold structure... So I thought it would not hurt to explain why this is a manifold. And a trivial one, since it is an open subset of a Banach space. And I took the Banach algebra viewpoint because it is a central point in Banach algebras. Using the determinant is neat in finite dimension, but it does not help much in Banach algebras... So why not do all at once?

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, considered as a manifold, then the tangent space is $V$ at any point. And $\mathrm{Aut}$ is an open subspace of the vector space $\mathrm{End}$. This doesn't have anything to do with Lie groups.

Comment: My turn: since you don't make the topology explicit, you might want to say that your vector space is finite-dimensional. And why don't you give the determinant argument yourself?

Comment: Actually, it does not follow instantly from the definition. If you know the manifold structure of $Aut(T_eG)$ the fact that the tangent space is $End(T_eG)$ is a tautology.